# Python: TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error'

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask and I'm trying to make an error show up when one of the form parts haven't been filled in. When I test this (filling in all the form parts), it gives me the error: "TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error'". What am I doing wrong?

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/crudcourse', methods = ['POST'])
def crudcourse():
db = get_db()
error = None

button = request.form['submitcourse']

coursename = request.form['coursename']
description = request.form['description']

if coursename != None or description != None:
    error = 'Vul alle velden in aub'
else:
    if button == 'Toevoegen':
        db.execute('insert into courses (coursename, description) 
        values(?, ?)', coursename, description)
        db.commit()
        flash('Gegevens sucessvol toegevoegd')

    elif button == 'Updaten':
        db.execute('update courses set coursename=?, description=? where
        coursename=? or description=?',
        coursename, description, coursename, description)
        db.commit()
        flash('Gegevens sucessvol geupdate')

    elif button == 'Verwijderen':
        db.execute('delete from courses where coursename=? or
        description=?', coursename, description)
        db.commit()
        flash('Gegevens sucessvol verwijderd')  

return redirect('/intranet/richtingen.html', error=error)
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/style.css">
</head>

<body>

{% if error %}
<p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
{% endif %}

{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}

    <div id="courses">
        <form action="/crudcourse" method="post">
            <p>Naam<input type="text" name="coursename"></p>
            <p>Beschrijving
                <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="4">
                </textarea></p>

            <input type="submit" name="submitcourse" value="Toevoegen">
            </input>
            <input type="submit" name="submitcourse" value="Updaten">
            </input>
            <input type="submit" name="submitcourse" value="Verwijderen">
            </input>
        </form>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste the code from image here , it will be more readable for us.

Comment: Well, isn't the error message clear enough? The `redirect` object doesn't know what to do with the keyword argument `error`. See API documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.redirect

Comment: @Arman I pasted the code on it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the redirect method you're referring to is the one that is provided from the flask library, `flask.redirect`. That can be imported like this:

```
from flask import redirect
```

If this is true, this redirect method doesn't take an error argument, as the error message is saying `TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error'`.

It seems like what you want to do is to pass any potential errors to the `/intranet/richtingen.html` page, if so - I would recommend doing so in a query string to the URL instead, like this:

```
return redirect('/intranet/richtingen.html?error=%s' % error)
```

Comment: That's what I want to do. But I think I found the solution myself, I was using redirect instead of render_template. Thank you for the help